# How to preserve text when saving ggplot2 as .svg?

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, knitr

I am trying to save a ggplot2 plot in svg format. I am not using the ggsave function because the plot is generated as part of a knitr document - the device I specify for plotting is 'svg'.

The problem is that text elements from the original plot appear as paths in the svg file, at least when opened in inkscape. The source code of the svg does not look like it contains any text either.

My plotting function is defined in a separate file:

```
## @knitr plot_histogram
ggplot(mainFrame[complete.cases(mainFrame),]) 
+ geom_boxplot(aes(x=source, y = pPfam, fill = source)) 
+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))
```

In the knitr document, I call the function and save the image using the 'svg' device.

````
```{r plot_histogram, dev = 'svg', fig.width= 7, fig.height=4, fig.show='hold', fig.path="figure/summary"}
```
````

So I'm not sure how to tell the 'svg' device or ggplot2 that I want to preserve text when saving svg? I would also be happy to use another graphics device if that solves the problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Neither the `svg()` device in base R nor the `CairoSVG()` device in the `Cairo` package supports this. All texts are turned into glyphs like

```
<symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 3.921875 -2.046875 L 3.921875 0.... "/>
</symbol>
```

I do not know why this has to be the case, and you may want to file a feature request to the r-devel mailing list. This question is not specific to `ggplot2`/`knitr`. It comes from the SVG device.

### Update

The OP pointed out that the `RSvgDevice` actually works, and we can specify the device by:

```
my_svg <- function(file, width, height) {
  library(RSvgDevice)
  devSVG(file = file, width = width, height = height, bg = "white", fg = "black",
         onefile = TRUE, xmlHeader = TRUE)
}
```

Then in `knitr` code chunks, use the option `dev='my_svg'`.

Comment: Yihui thanks for your answer - I might try and request this from the r-devel list then because I think it would be very useful to keep the text selectable/editable.

Comment: Seems there is already a device that supports text. It's called `RSvgDevice`. This links to it on [cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSvgDevice/)

Comment: So this works with a [custom graphics device](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) for knitr eg. `my_svg <- function(file, width, height){ devSVG(file = file, width = width, height = height, bg = "white", fg = "black", onefile=TRUE, xmlHeader=TRUE)}` and setting `dev = 'my_svg'`. Perfect!

Comment: RSvgDevice seems to be deprecated, I cannot install it in R 3.3.1 (not available for this version, though I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: However, after updating R (since April (war R 3.2.5), it seems that it works now. Or the reason that it works now is, that I manually installed `install.packages(''gridSVG'')` although I did not load the package explicitly before reexporting just now.

Comment: @TobiO You may install the **svglite** package and use `dev = 'svglite'`

Comment: thanks. later in the day, I found, that there were some issues, when editing the text elements in the axis labels. I will try your suggestion when I'm done writing ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately svglite produces now output, where the textboxes stay the same size, but the text is being distorted when opening in inkscape and e.g. changing fonts or trying to type text. gridSVG works with text, but doesn't export transparency (alpha) properly

Comment: I finally got it to work.
After export with svglite open the file once in inkscape, make some spurious change and save the file
Then use a text editor and remove all the lines that have the follwing format:
lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" and
textLength="8.00px" (use regex textLength.*\n )
Save and enjoy in inkscape

Comment: @TobiO Update: The fix actually does work. This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also save the plots as PDF; after, convert them to SVG (optimised: for a small size; and the precision have to be bigger than 4 for good images) using the Inkscape.

Comment: that could have been a comment.

Comment: however, when using this with ggplot geom_points, the pch is not conserved. all standard dots (pch 16 i think) are shown as 'q'

Answer (score 0):

Now
`ggsave("plot_using_svglite.svg",device = svglite::svglite)`

renders the text correctly.